# How to prevent some columns from changing rowstate in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a datasource dtDataMain , I have roughly 18 columns - the last two columns 17 and 18 are merged into the dtDataMain (if that matters to some one). 
I also have a checkedlistbox which is a representation of selected items in an intermediary table dtSelections.

I have some *pseudo* code:

```
dtDataMain.Merge(dtSelections, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)
MyDataGridViewBindingSource.DataSource = dtDataMain
MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyDataGridViewBindingSource
```

I merged the two tables because I wanted the database to provide the initial csv(Comma Separated Values) data that will populate all of the rows of the datagridview.
 I use a checkedlistbox for the possible selections that make up that csv text and depending on my checked or not checked status I set the values in the datgridview cells and also in my bindingsource.

My Problem here is datgridview fires databinding complete - which I do not want it to do. Is there any way that I can accept changes in the COLUMN 17 and 18 of the row - and any changes in the rest of the columns are persisted?

**EDIT 1: 9/27/2016**
I need to add this here as it is too lengthy for the comment field:
I know the rows have changed since I merged the tables I acceptChanges  on the merged table (lefthandside)  to clear that. 
 I ran getChanges to verify all was good - no changes. I add the datasource to the dataGridView - it binds and then fires the bindingcomplete event,

> in the bindingcomplete event I find that somehow 2 rows changed row(0)
>   and Row(1) - there are 30 rows. I do not know why this happens.

So I am trying to decouple the columns that I merged from the DataGridView ,  I merged them because the SQL server supplies the CSV nicely,and when I save the data the DataGridView comes back with those two added columns with data.

Previously with the two columns unbound when I did  a save of the data the datagridview would not show the unbound data - just empty columns. That means every save I have to write all the rows of data in the format and order just like I am getting from the db and I also need to do it on every load and make sure it is synced with the data in each of those rows. Which is the reason for my strange question. I also have controls bound to the datasource.

So I am at the chicken and the egg - 
Maybe someone has a better way to do this?

Comment: The Datadinging complete event has nothing to do with the RowState,  Any changes to the rowstate may have happened when you merged.  Its hard to follow what you are asking

Comment: You can always do a For...Each and process each row as you want.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b I updated the info.

Comment: @Plutonix Databinding Complete gets fired because my checkedListBox updates the underlying datasource which is bound to DGV  and I have the rows that changed - but I do not want to indicate any row changes if either of those two columns. changed. I'am trying to prevent that. - so when row gets changed, dgv resumes binding, and .dbcomplete fires.

Comment: You question is still not clear.  The DataBindingComplete will fire when you first set the DataSource - it is supposed to. The 2 columns merged into the destination DT dont have to change the row state, but this will: `...I set the values in the datgridview cells and also in my bindingsource`.  If you change a row, the row state changes

Comment: @Plutonix - I know the databinding complete will fire when the datasource is set. I understand the row state changes when a row gets changed. I want to inhibit the rowstate changed for those two columns. The other columns change of row state is fine - and what I want. but on these two columns - I do not want it to set row state changed .

Comment: If you dont want row changes to be tracked, you cant add those 2 columns to the datatable - add them to the DGV instead.

Comment: @Plutonix - yes adding them there results in every time I commit the DGV bindingsource.AcceptChanges() or DiscardChanges by a row or by table - the DGV redraws - which means I need to iterate rows and populate - keeping them in sync as well. Each time I load I need to iterate rows. - I was trying to avoid those two scenarios as well - but alas I think that is what I am stuck with.